# selection of people's contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to select people from an image. I have an image with some amount of people standing in a row (they don't touch each other). For my goal I used `imutils` ([some functions for image proceessing](https://github.com/minooei/imutils)).

Algorithm for which I work:

I binarized the image, then apply a canny filter, and then I used the function `cv::findContours` to find the outlines, then sort the outlines from left to right and enumerate them, but it doesn't work with people who have white pieces in clothes, and I get something like this:

[image: result image]

How can i solve it? Here is my code:

```
int main() {
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
sorting_contours();
return 0;}
void sorting_contours() {
    Mat image = imread("6.jpg");
    Mat orig = image.clone();
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(gray, gray, 245, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat edged = imutils::auto_canny(gray);
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    cv::findContours(edged, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,
                     CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    vector<Rect> boundRect;
    contours = imutils::sort_contours(contours, boundRect, imutils::SortContoursMethods::left_to_right);
    Mat sortedImage = image.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        sortedImage = imutils::label_contour(sortedImage, vector<vector<Point> >(1, contours[i]), i,
                                             cv::Scalar(240, 0, 159));
    }
    imshow("left_to_right", sortedImage);
    waitKey(0);

}
```

Original image:

[image]

Result with inverted thresholded image and dilate + erode:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the original image? (use the edit button in your question) I would like to test it

Comment: Implement a "fill hole" function. (Seed fill the background and complement the blobs left.)

Comment: I forgot to mention it before, the image background has to be black and the objects which you want to find the contour should be white... just invert the image before finding the contours. `255-edged`

Comment: @api55 [link](https://imgur.com/a/NI6aO9g)

Comment: @api55 i tried inverse it, and applied dilate + erode and got clean silhouett, but he numbers him twice [result](https://imgur.com/a/DxqcbBk)

Comment: It looks like if it was drawing the same contour twice (I do not see 2 contours) Can you try not to sort and label them and to draw them with drawContours like in the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) with random colors, to at least be able to differentiate between them and notice which are the two contours and what is happening. BTW, I edited your question and added the images you gave me

Comment: @api55 Oh, now i see [contours](https://imgur.com/a/aWKlfuL), but why it can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial code had a couple of mistakes. The first one is that the image expects the source to be white objects in black background, but you have the opposite. This is easily solved by doing:

```
image =  255 - image; // this is the image you already thresholded
```

Then it has another problem, it gives you a broken line. That is because you are passing a canny image, which not necessarily has a continuous line. Even more, you use the automatic one, which may be good, but not necessarily perfect. The following example worked for me:

```
  // load data and threshold it
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread(R"(a.jpg)"), gray;
  cv::cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
  cv::threshold(gray, gray, 210, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
  // invert the image
  gray = 255 - gray;
  // close the gaps this is equivalent to dilate+erode
  cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(9, 9), cv::Point(4, 4));
  cv::morphologyEx(gray, gray, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, element);
  // get the contours
  std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
  cv::findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
  std::cout << "Found " << contours.size() << " contours" << std::endl;
```

This returns exactly 4 contours. You may try to adapt your code with this example to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Only take into account the outer contours in the hierarchy returned by findcontours.

Comment: You mean mode - CV_RETR_EXTERNAL or what?

Comment: @MaksimPekarev: that's it.